# Retrieve images from asset folder?

Tags: android

In activity class i did this coding...I have few images in assets/folder1/hello.png,hi.png,love.png..i want to retrieve the path of the each image file ??

```
final String ASSETS_URI ="file:///android_asset";
final String[] IMAGE_IDS =new String[] {ASSETS_URI+"/"+"one.png",ASSETS_URI+"/"+"two.png",ASSETS_URI+"/"+"three.png"};

iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv);
if(i>=0 & i< IMAGE_IDS.length-1)
   i=i+1;
else if(i==IMAGE_IDS.length-1)
   i=0;

iv.setImageURI(Uri.parse(IMAGE_IDS[i]));
```

Comment: try this https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/10/02/store-and-use-files-in-assets/

Comment: what error you faced here?

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code:

```
       AssetManager manager = getAssets();

        try {
            InputStream open = manager.open("one.png");
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(open);
            // Assign the bitmap to an ImageView in this layout
            ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
            view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: i already give you too much code.now you have to put your code in this part as per your requirement..

Comment: what is your actual requirement?

Comment: I have multiple images in different folders in assest folder..and i want to retrieve multiple images from assest folder....

Comment: i want to retrieve multiple images from assest folder. what does that means??

Comment: There are 10 images in folder1(Eg: assets/folder1/img1, assets/folder1/img2, ...... assets/folder1/img10) and 10 images in folder2 (Eg: assets/folder2/img1, assets/folder2/img2, ......assets/folder2/img10) So I want to use these 20 images in my java file. So provide the details about this.